# Spring MVC request is too slow

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a web app that used Spring MVC framework, Tomcat for 7 for front end that call Websphere for back end.

In some pages I have jsp files that call controllers for inserting or updating data. 
This work well when I try to send a few data but when I try to send more data the application cant response and goes to timeout. The problem is.. for example when I click on a href to open a page passing input data  this cant go in the controller method( or it is very slow). So the problem is not the back end and nor the front end I think. 
But I dont know what I ve to do.. Any suggestion?

Thnx

Comment: Use SQLPROFILER to find put which query is taking the longest to run and try resolving it. Here is a link to free SQL PROFILER https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/

Comment: It doesnt call any query, it stops before. When I click on href it tries to send the request but goes in loop and never enter neither in the controller. I launche the app from localhost

Comment: Open your browser console to see if any errors or exceptions. Not reaching the controller seems you might be missing any required parameters or something. check your network tabs as well

Comment: I checked and no errors. It simply waits to call.. infact when I try with few data input to send it works fine but when I try with many it beahvs in this way..I dont know what it does between the click and the calling method.maybe some network check?? I dont know...

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Did you check your "Network" tab?

Comment: I use IE 11 or I tried also with chrome.. chrome is a bit faster but however also it goes in loop.. the network tab shows that it call the method from controller(I can see all the input in the request) but remains in suspend.. for some minutes(about 3-5minutes)..

Comment: Anything under the response tab? See something like. An error has occurred................

Comment: No.. is empty until return the response. It is just slow but it works.. The main problem is between the click and the controller method. Cause after the calling query works and is fast. When I click it loads differents css, js files without error and tries to call the method and here it stops some minutes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149510/discussion-between-user8271644-and-travis-91).

Answer (score 1):

1. Try it without debug mode.
2. All heavy logic handling behind controllers should be in async mode.
3. Use performance testing to detect your *bottle neck*.

---

If you interesting in solution for your concrete case, I will improve my answer if you share your application via [git](https://github.com/).

Comment: the bottle neck is between click and the controller method calling.. it takes few minutes to complete the request. I dont know what is it between the click on href and the method controller..

Comment: Do you have a java script request builders & handlers on your web? Can you share it also?

Comment: I have an href request that call method controller.. now I cant share.! But fyi when I try to pass few data it works fine.. the problem is when I click on href and controlling the network tab on my browser I see that it tries to send the request but it takes a long time

Comment: **1.** Check your javascript. **2.** You should check all request handlers on transport level (there are can be some proxies, firewalls and so on). To skip transport level checking you should try your application on PC where no proxies, security restrictions, no request zippers... **3.** If in `very trusted` space everything ok, you could continue considering how to add proxy by proxy in your request handlers and other staffs. **4.** If request time on `very trusted` space will be to big, you should consider before `controller handlers` (WebFilters, ControllerAdvice, AOP Interceptors).

Comment: For sure there is a proxy and I cant deactive this.. I should controll maybe if there are web filters but I dont think so. I launch everything in localhost then there not other calling..

Comment: _To skip transport level checking you should try your application on PC where no proxies, security restrictions, no request zippers..._

Comment: I debug the code and I seen that it locks on JIoEnpoint$Worker.run()... Why with many datas it stops?

Comment: You can not be sure that it stops on controller level exactly. To be sure thats controllers issue exactly, you should exclude all steps i've pointed before.